# Basic Array based stack in java

Tags: java, stack

Here is an array based stack. I tried to implement this basic stack from memory. I want to make sure it is correct.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Stack{
    private int[] stack;
    private int size;

    public Stack(){
        stack = new int[5];
        int size = 0;
    }

    public Stack(int capacity){
        stack = new int[capacity];
        int size = 0;
    }

    public void push(int pushedValue){
        if(size == stack.length){
            throw new fullStackException();
        }
        stack[size] = pushedValue;
        size++;
    }

    public int pop(){
        if(size == 0){
            throw new emptyStackException();
        }
        int poppedValue = stack[size - 1];
        size--;
        return poppedValue;
    }

    public int peek(){
        if(size == 0){
            throw new emptyStackException();
        }
        return stack[size - 1];
    }

    private class emptyStackException extends RuntimeException{
        public emptyStackException(){
            super();
        }
    }

    private class fullStackException extends RuntimeException{
        public fullStackException(){
            super();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you look up a proper implementation and compare it to yours? Figuring out why they did something that you didn't do will be a far more valuable experience.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems to be ok, a simple unit test prove it works.

However, using such private exceptions is not a good idea because nobody can catch them. You should also use the CamelCase name for those exceptions and maybe provide more context information to those exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your stack is a fixed size, which is fine, but you could make it expand and shrink like an `ArrayList` does if you were interested: double size when maximum capacity reached, halve size when quarter capacity reached.

Maybe something else to think about is adding a method that would return the current or maximum size if you think that would be useful; it's up to you.  Something I would recommend, however, is implementing an `isEmpty` and maybe an `isFull` method.  Having an `isEmpty` method would be very useful when popping everything off a stack rather than waiting for an `emptyStackException`.  But if a user decides to ignore the return value from `isEmpty` or possibly `isFull`, then it's their own fault for invoking the exception.

I agree with @Anonymous about those exception classes being capitalized.  Classes in Java should be TitleCase; methods, fields, and other variables in camelCase; and final fields and enums in UPPER_CASE.  That's just some general Java variable naming conventions.